# Google app script charts blanks

Tags: javascript, charts, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this code to save a chart from a tab/sheet in a spreadsheet in googledocs to my googledrive. The chart is always blank. Similar code to send an inline chart in email has the same issue.

Chart is a column graph of durations on a given date. The saved file is of the right shape and rectangle of about the right size but just blank. What is the problem?

```
function exportGraph(ss,CoaName)
{ // ladd named chart to google drive


    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(CoaName);
    ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);


    var charts = sheet.getCharts();

    if ( charts.length >0 )
    {  // chart on this page email it
        var chart= sheet.getCharts()[0].getAs("image/png").setName(CoaName+".png");
        var file = DocsList.createFile(chart);  
        file.rename(CoaName+".png");  
        file.addToFolder(DocsList.getFolder("Charts"));   

    }
}
```

Comment: Similar to reported [Issue 2877](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2877).